# Redirecting multiple directories in subdomain to normal domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do this with htaccess but it's not working properly.

For example, I need to redirect:

http://sub.domain.com/category/ to http://www.domain.com/sub/category/
http://sub.domain.com/category/movies/ to http://www.domain.com/sub/listings/movies/
http://sub.domain.com/category/movies/horror/ to http://www.domain.com/sub/listings/movies/horror/
http://sub.domain.com/events/ to http://www.domain.com/sub/local/events/

Here's what I tried to do, but some of them like /category/ are catching all of them.  I want to do exact match with just a trailing slash and no slash and that's it.  Not sub folders or files.  I'm placing the htaccess file in the sub.domain.com root.

```
Redirect 301 /category/ http://www.domain.com/sub/category/
Redirect 301 /category/movies/ http://www.domain.com/sub/listings/movies/
Redirect 301 /category/movies/horror/ http://www.domain.com/sub/listings/movies/horror/
Redirect 301 /events/ http://www.domain.com/sub/local/events/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier with mod_rewrite directives, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/category/?$   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://www.domain.com/sub/category/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/category/movies/?$   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    http://www.domain.com/sub/listings/movies/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/category/movies/horror/?$   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    http://www.domain.com/sub/listings/movies/horror/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/events/?$   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    http://www.domain.com/sub/local/events/ [R=301,L]
```

According to:

`I want to do exact match with just a trailing slash and no slash and that's it.  Not sub folders or files.`

It will redirect permanently the URLs as described in your question